# How do I optimize this sql query that takes forever?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize this query as it takes 30 seconds to execute:

```
SELECT
   TOP 100 table1.* 
FROM
   table1 (NOLOCK)     
INNER JOIN
   DB1..table2 (NOLOCK) 
      ON DB1..table2.id = DB1..table1.id    
INNER JOIN
   DB1..table2_batch (NOLOCK) 
      ON DB1..table2_batch.table2_batch_id = DB1..table2.table2_batch_id    
INNER JOIN
   DB2..table4 (NOLOCK) 
      ON CASE 
         WHEN CHARINDEX(':',
      table2_batch.reference_number,
      3) > 3 THEN SUBSTRING(table2_batch.reference_number,
      3,
      CHARINDEX(':',
      table2_batch.reference_number,
      3) -3 ) 
      ELSE 
   RIGHT(table2_batch.reference_number,
   LEN(table2_batch.reference_number) -2) 
end = Cast(table4.PurchaseOrderID as int)    INNER JOIN
   DB2..table3 (NOLOCK) 
      ON  DB2..table3.key =  DB2..table4.key 
WHERE
   table1.id IS NOT NULL  
   AND (
      table1.id!='' 
      OR table1.id IS NULL
   ) 
   AND   DB2..table3.AccountTypeID != 30000 
   AND CHARINDEX('O', DB1..table2_batch.reference_number) = 1 
   AND  table1_id NOT IN (
      select
         lim.table1_id 
      from
         link_table1_message as lim (nolock) 
      inner join
         table1 as i (nolock)  
            on i.table1_id = lim.table1_id 
      where
         lim.message_id >= 90
   ) 
ORDER BY
   last_hit DESC
```

Comment: Wouldn't this question fit better to code review?

Comment: Simplify the query by removing `join`s and find out where the performance bottleneck is.  Then post another question about a simpler query.

Comment: What's your schema like? How many rows are involved in which tables? Are any indexes hit? What's the execution plan looking like?

Comment: I don't have access to the execution plan on the database where it runs slow. There are many records in each table 10,000+ at least in each table. Everything is indexed. The joins are necessary for the query to select the proper data, no way around that.

Comment: The bottleneck is on the DB2..table4 join. When I take that part out it does the query really fast ... but I really need that join in there to make sure the proper condition is met for this scenario.

Comment: With a little bit more context in the question itself, this could be a good fit for [codereview.se], indeed. `ON CASE WHEN...` joins don't smell very good either. Have you tried CTE's?

Comment: What is a CTE? Didn't realize there was a Code Review site ... I don't really consider SQL queries code though lol

Comment: To add some context, the query is going to pull users that are only from a certain group of sellers. The data that tells you if they are a part of that group lives in another database DB2 and the lookup index is actually buried in a field that has a value like this: "O:123456" so we first have to look for the records with the right letter before the : and then take the index from the part after the :

Comment: There is no information here that's necessary to help you. This has zero chance of receiving a useful answer. The existing answers just received a -1 from me because they are random guesses. Who knows what element of this query is slow?! Noone can. To help you resolve the problem: Learn about query tuning in general or post a lot more information (query plan, schema, ...).

Comment: @usr when has a `case when` and a useless `cast` ever been beneficial to performance in an `on` clause?

Comment: @Mat'sMug who knows if that join is even important? The joined tables might consist of zero rows. 99.9999% of the time could be spent elsewhere. **Noone knows anything.** I have tuned 100s of queries and I don't have any idea what's slow here. **You cannot tell from the query alone, ever.**

Comment: @usr for the record I wrote my answer based on [OP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014136/how-do-i-optimize-this-sql-query-that-takes-forever#comment46273590_29014136) about the bottleneck being in the `DB2..table4` join. Guess indeed, but a somewhat *educated* one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014136/how-do-i-optimize-this-sql-query-that-takes-forever#comment46273590_29014136):

> *The bottleneck is on the DB2..table4 join. When I take that part out it does the query really fast ... but I really need that join in there to make sure the proper condition is met for this scenario.*

It's a little bit of a guess because we don't know how many rows are involved, nor what your schema looks like, but making a few assumptions, this *could possibly* help:

> ```
> INNER JOIN
>    DB2..table4 (NOLOCK) 
>       ON CASE 
>          WHEN CHARINDEX(':',
>       table2_batch.reference_number,
>       3) > 3 THEN SUBSTRING(table2_batch.reference_number,
>       3,
>       CHARINDEX(':',
>       table2_batch.reference_number,
>       3) -3 ) 
>       ELSE 
>    RIGHT(table2_batch.reference_number,
>    LEN(table2_batch.reference_number) -2) 
> end = Cast(table4.PurchaseOrderID as int)
> ```

That's a lot of logic to put in a `join` I find.

You have `table2_batch` that has a `reference_number` that's encoding a value that you'll end up needing to extract and use to join with `table4.PurchaseOrderID`; I'd start by selecting that first:

```
with cteTable2 as (
    select
        table2_batch_id
       ,reference_number
       ,case when charindex(':',reference_number,3) > 3 
             then substring(reference_number,3,charindex(':',reference_number,3) - 3)
             else right(reference_number,len(reference_number) - 2)
        end PurchaseOrderID
    from table2_batch
)
```

And then you can treat `cteTable2` as a full-fledged table in the `select` statement that follows, so instead of joining with `table2_batch`, you join with `cteTable2`:

```
inner join DB2..table4 (NOLOCK)
    on cteTable2.PurchaseOrderID = cast(table4.PurchaseOrderID as int)
```

...and is that `cast` really needed?